# Android Cordova - Mp3 Audio not playing

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I am having trouble with playing sound on android device It plays well in browser and iOS

```
 function playSound() 
 {
    var snd = new Audio( 'file://android_asset/www/sounds/melody.mp3');     
    snd.play();
 }
```

It plays well in the browser but it doesn't play on the device. I see following logs on the device:

I am having start called in state 0
08-30 10:37:42.766 4577-4641/com.k.numbersense E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)

Can you please suggest how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: are you calling the function after `OnDeviceReady()` event?

Comment: Yes. I am calling  above mentioned function after device ready is fired.

Comment: I also installed "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media" and replaced Audio object with Media. But still it doesn't work on android device. Volume is also set to full.